# Why do I get array to string conversion error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following two SQL queries the first one looks up the `partner_id` in a table called `orders`, the second one changes the partner name using the `partner_id` but I get the error "array to string conversion".

How to set `partner_id` to be an integer?

```
$partner_id_ = DB::select('select partner_id from orders where id = ? ', [$id]);

DB::update('update partners set name = ? where id =?',[$partner,$partner_id_]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$partner_id_ = DB::select('select partner_id from orders where id = ? ', [$id]);
```

Defines `$partner_id_` as an array with 1 element of stdClass with single property `partner_id`.

If you are sure that you will always find at least one row there, change `$partner_id_` to `$partner_id_[0]->partner_id` in the following line:

```
DB::update('update partners set name = ? where id =?',[$partner,$partner_id_[0]->partner_id]);
```

Comment: i am sure that i will find single row but i still face a problem stating that `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`